# Javascript regex invalid range in character class

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a regex pattern that I got from regexlib to validate relative urls. On their site you can [test](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=2888) the pattern to make sure it fits your needs. Everything works great on their site, as soon as I use the pattern in mine I get the error message:

> Invalid range in character class

I know that this error usually means that a hyphen is mistakenly being used to represent a range and is not properly escaped. But in this case since it works on their site I'm confused why it's not working on mine.

```
var urlRegex = new RegExp('^(?:(?:\.\./)|/)?(?:\w(?:[\w`~!$=;\-\+\.\^\(\)\|\{\}\[\]]|(?:%\d\d))*\w?)?(?:/\w(?:[\w`~!$=;\-\+\.\^\(\)\|\{\}\[\]]|(?:%\d\d))*\w?)*(?:\?[^#]+)?(?:#[a-z0-9]\w*)?$', 'g');
```

**NOTE:**
If you're going to test the regex from their site (using the link above) be sure to change the `Regex Engine` dropdown to `Client-side Engine` and the `Engine` dropdown to `Javascript`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Either put `-` at the **end** or **beginning** of the character class **or** use  **two backslashes** to do a regex escape within **string**

since you are using string you need to use **two backslashes** for each special characters..

---

**NOTE**

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514349/javascript-regex-where-to-use-escape-characters) answer on SO which explains when to use single or double backslashes to escape special characters

Comment: I moved it to the end in both character classes but now I get `Invalid quantifier`

Comment: couldn't I also double escape the hyphen ie(`\\-`) instead of moving it to the end?

Comment: @bflemi3 yes indeed you can escape it..check out the link i have specified in the ans

Comment: @bflemi3 since you are using string you need to use **two backslashes** for each escape sequence..that would solve your problem..

Comment: Just figured that out and answered my own question. I'll delete it and give you credit. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to use `RegExp` constructor here. Just use `RegExp` literal:

```
var urlRegex = /^(?:(?:\.\.\/)|\/)?(?:\w(?:[\w`~!$=;\-\+\.\^\(\)\|\{\}\[\]]|(?:%\d\d))*\w?)?(?:\/\w(?:[\w`~!$=;\-\+\.\^\(\)\|\{\}\[\]]|(?:%\d\d))*\w?)*(?:\?[^#]+)?(?:#[a-z0-9]\w*)?$/g;
               ^           ^   ^                                                               ^                                                                                     ^
```

Inside `RegExp` literal, you just write the regex naturally, except for `/`, which now needs escaping, since `/` is used as delimiter in the `RegExp` literal.

In character class, `^` has special meaning at the beginning of the character class, `-` has special meaning in between 2 characters, and `\` has special meaning, which is to escape other characters (mainly `^`, `-`, `[`, `]` and `\`) and also to specify shorthand character classes (`\d`, `\s`, `\w`, ...). `[`, `]` are used as delimiters for character class, so they also have special meaning. (Actually, in JavaScript, only `]` has special meaning, and you can specify `[` without escaping inside character class). Other than those 5 character listed above, other characters (unless involved in an escape sequence with `\`) doesn't have any special meaning.

You can reduce the number of escaping `\` with the information above. For `^`, unless it is the only character in the character class, you can put it away from the beginning of the character class. For `-`, you can put it at the end of the character class.

```
var urlRegex = /^(?:(?:\.\.\/)|\/)?(?:\w(?:[\w`~!$=;+.^()|{}\[\]-]|(?:%\d\d))*\w?)?(?:\/\w(?:[\w`~!$=;+.^()|{}\[\]-]|(?:%\d\d))*\w?)*(?:\?[^#]+)?(?:#[a-z0-9]\w*)?$/g;
```

What was changed:

```
[\w`~!$=;\-\+\.\^\(\)\|\{\}\[\]]
[\w`~!$=;+.^()|{}\[\]-]
```