# problem with caret and dollar sign regex in nodejs

Tags: node.js, regex

in node js when i try to check for validation of incoming string using express-validator it doesn't match using

```
check('firstName').matches('^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-$]')
```

to parse firstName of incoming request body

Note I've edited the question to be like

```
check('firstName').matches('^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-]$')
```

Comment: You are opening a character class `[` but I don't see you closing it `]`.

Comment: Also maybe try a `/regex/` instead of a `'string'`.

Comment: i've edited it but u mean to put it like this `check('firstName').matches('/^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-$]/')`

Comment: it doesn't work this way i've tested it

Comment: as it stands what you have will capture the first character. You can repeat the expresion adding a `*` to it such as `^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-$]*`

Comment: If you want to match the whole string and there can not be spaces only (but `'  '` is valid for example) try `let regex = /^[a-zA-Z'-]+(?: [a-zA-Z'-]+)*$/;`

Comment: I meant `.matches(/stuff/)` and not `.matches('stuff')`

Comment: `.matches(/stuff/) ` rly worked for me thx bro and the second thing i want to match only strings that start with a character and may contain a space in between and end with ' or - or character @CherryDT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

express was treating the string in different way than /regex/ this was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues here:

- The range issue because of `\-`. You should use double escaping character instead.
- The given regex will only match the first character because the quantifier is missing. You should use the `+` (one or more characters) quantifier at the end of the regex for full match.

The correct regex for your case would be:

`check('firstName').matches('^[a-zA-Z\s\'\\-$]+')`

Comment: no it's not because of that because the \- is at the end look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572123/javascript-regex-invalid-range-in-character-class) so it is not the problem

Comment: If you don't put the double backslash then you will get the error about range issue.

Comment: that if it is not in the end of the state like in my case up there look at the edit